# Little copy tool

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

I made a little copy tool, but my progress bar seems to be too slow. I would also be very interested in any tips and improvements or code smells.

`MainForm` (code behind):

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private FileCopy _fileCopy;
    private delegate void UpdateProgressEventHandler(object o, CopyProgressChangedEventArgs e);
    private delegate void UpdateProgressFinishedEventHandler();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Source_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox_SourcePath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Destination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox_DestinationPath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void Button_Copy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar_Copy.Value = 0;

        if ((textBox_SourcePath.Text != String.Empty) &&
            textBox_DestinationPath.Text != String.Empty)
        {
            _fileCopy = new FileCopy(textBox_SourcePath.Text, textBox_DestinationPath.Text);

            _fileCopy.CopyProgressChangedEvent += FileCopy_CopyProgressChangedEvent;
            _fileCopy.CopyProgressFinishedEvent += FileCopy_CopyProgressFinishedEvent;
            _fileCopy.StartCopyAsync();
            button_Copy.Enabled = false;
            button_Copy.Text = "Cancel";
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Check you Path Inputs!", "INPUT ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    public void FileCopy_CopyProgressChangedEvent(object sender, CopyProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new UpdateProgressEventHandler(FileCopy_CopyProgressChangedEvent), new object[] { sender, e });

        else
        {
            var state = e.State;

            progressBar_Copy.Value = (int)state.Progress;
            label_CopyFile.Text = "Copying... " + state.Filename;
            label_FileCount.Text = "[" + state.FilesCopyied.ToString() + "/" + state.FileCount.ToString() + "]";
        }
    }

    private void FileCopy_CopyProgressFinishedEvent()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(new UpdateProgressFinishedEventHandler(FileCopy_CopyProgressFinishedEvent));
        else
        {
            progressBar_Copy.Value = 100;
            label_CopyFile.Text = "Copying Done!";
            button_Copy.Text = "Back Me Up!";
            button_Copy.Enabled = true;
        }        
    }

}
```

`FileCopy` class:

```
class FileCopy
{
    DirectoryInfo _sourceDictInfo;
    DirectoryInfo _destDictInfo;
    private BackgroundWorker _copyWorker;
    private List<FileInfo> _filesToCopy;
    private bool _override = true;

    public delegate void CopyProgressChangedHandler(object sender, CopyProgressChangedEventArgs e);
    public delegate void CopyProgressFinishedHandler();
    public event CopyProgressChangedHandler CopyProgressChangedEvent;
    public event CopyProgressFinishedHandler CopyProgressFinishedEvent;

    #region Events
    protected void OnCopyProgressChangedEvent(CopyProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = CopyProgressChangedEvent;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected void OnCopyProgressFinishedEvent()
    {
        var handler = CopyProgressFinishedEvent;
        handler?.Invoke();
    }
    #endregion

    public FileCopy(string sourcePath, string destPath)
    {
        _filesToCopy = new List<FileInfo>();
        _copyWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _sourceDictInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
        _destDictInfo = new DirectoryInfo(destPath);
    }

    public void StartCopyAsync()
    {
        _copyWorker.DoWork += CopyWorker_DoWork;
        _copyWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _copyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void CopyWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        CopyDirectory(_sourceDictInfo.FullName, _destDictInfo.FullName);
    }

    private void CopyDirectory(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
    {
        CopyState state = new CopyState();
        CollectFilesToCopy(sourcePath, state, _filesToCopy);

        foreach (FileInfo file in _filesToCopy)
        {
            char[] trimChars = sourcePath.ToCharArray();
            string newPartOfDestinationDirectory = file.FullName.TrimStart(trimChars);
            string destinationDirectory = _destDictInfo.FullName;
            string targetFile = destinationDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + newPartOfDestinationDirectory;

            try
            {
                state.Filename = file.Name;
                state.AllreadyCopiedSize += file.Length;
                state.FilesCopyied++;
                OnCopyProgressChangedEvent(new CopyProgressChangedEventArgs(state));
                File.Copy(file.FullName, targetFile, _override);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Fancy Logging Magic....
            }
        }                       
        OnCopyProgressFinishedEvent();
    }


    private void CollectFilesToCopy(string sourcePath, CopyState state, List<FileInfo> filesToCopy)
    {

        DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);

        FileInfo[] files = null;
        try
        {
            files = sourceDirectory.GetFiles();
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        { 
            // DO SOME LOGGING-MAGIC IN HERE...
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                state.MaxSize += file.Length;
                filesToCopy.Add(file);
                state.FileCount++;
            }
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] directories = null;
        try
        {
            directories = sourceDirectory.GetDirectories();
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // Do more logging Magic in here...
        }
        if (directories != null)
        foreach (DirectoryInfo direcotry in directories)
        {
            CollectFilesToCopy(direcotry.FullName, state, filesToCopy);
        }
    }

}
```

CopyState Class:

```
public class CopyState
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    private double _alreadyCopiedSize;
    public double AllreadyCopiedSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _alreadyCopiedSize;
        }
        set
        {
            Progress = (100 * (AllreadyCopiedSize / MaxSize)) == 0 ? 1 : (100 * (AllreadyCopiedSize / MaxSize));
            _alreadyCopiedSize = value;
        }
    }
    public double MaxSize { get; set; }
    public int FileCount { get; set; }
    public int FilesCopyied { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: The bottleneck of your copy tool seems to be the `File.Copy` API, see:  [File.Copy vs. Manual FileStream.Write For Copying File](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247042/235671).

Comment: Closed voted as broken code, no comment left, thus I voted to leave open because I don't see the actual brokenness

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions:

- you are using `BackgroundWorker` which is outdated, prefer `Task` instead
- a common cause for stuck progress bars is that calls happen too quickly for UI to update, you need to think **percentage progress** to overcome this situation

Haven't really bothered trying to fix your code :D instead I wrote the following, hopefully it'll give you some inspiration:

- it has 2 progress bars, one for current file, one for global
- handles sub-directories in source
- handles cancellation

[image]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
        private string _source;
        private string _target;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _source = PickFolder();
            labelSource.Text = _source;
            UpdateStartButton();
        }

        private void buttonTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _target = PickFolder();
            labelTarget.Text = _target;
            UpdateStartButton();
        }

        private async void buttonStartCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button) sender;
            if (button.Text == @"Start")
            {
                button.Text = @"Cancel";
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                await Task.Run((Action) Copy, _cts.Token);
            }
            else if (button.Text == @"Cancel")
            {
                button.Text = @"Start";
                _cts.Cancel();
            }
            else if (button.Text == @"Close")
            {
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void Copy()
        {
            var source = _source;
            var target = _target;
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var buffer = new byte[65536];
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var path in files)
            {
                var substring = path.Substring(source.Length + 1);
                var targetPath = Path.Combine(target, substring);
                var targetDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(targetPath);
                if (!Directory.Exists(targetDir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);

                var percent = 0;
                using (var input = File.OpenRead(path))
                using (var output = File.Create(targetPath))
                {
                    while (output.Length < input.Length)
                    {
                        if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                            goto canceled; // evil :)

                        var read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                        var percent1 = (int) Math.Floor(1.0d/input.Length*output.Length*100.0d);
                        if (percent1 > percent)
                        {
                            Invoke((Action) delegate { progressBar1.Value = percent1; });
                            percent = percent1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var percent3 = (int) (1.0d/files.Length*(i + 1)*100.0d);
                Invoke((Action) delegate { progressBar2.Value = percent3; });
                i++;
            }

            Invoke((Action) delegate { buttonStartCancel.Text = @"Close"; });
            return;

            canceled:
            Console.WriteLine(@"Operation canceled");

            // TODO handle things as needed
        }

        private void UpdateStartButton()
        {
            buttonStartCancel.Enabled = _source != null && _target != null && _source != _target;
        }

        private static string PickFolder()
        {
            using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                return dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? dialog.SelectedPath : null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, I will take a closer look on your code later this day. At a first look I got some nice ideas from you code I will build into mine (e.g. cancelation, tasks and have to think about the progress behavior). Thanks for that. At a Second look, I see no error handling (What if File does not exists anymore, Permission denied Exception and so on.) Second I see a "goto"... no comment on this ;-) And third, I don't think your code can handle large files because of your restricted buffer. Greetings

Comment: Well, cacellation is handled by the `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` and not by using a `goto` ;-)

Comment: @Locke that was really a quick sample I worked out and I've put a TODO at bottom; obviously there's quite more that is needed to have something robust.